# CodeIgniter Learning Tutorials for Beginners

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to learn CodeIgniter to use for a shopping site, but I am not having luck with the official doc. Does anyone know of anything that will help?

Comment: What specifically are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

re: CSS.

I've got my CSS a separate folder at the root. (same place as 'index.php') ... /content/css/main.css

Called as:

```
<link href="<?=base_url();?>content/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 4):

We've used Code Igniter on a couple of projects and found the videos on their site to be helpful for an intro:
http://codeigniter.com/tutorials/

Answer (score 3):

Specifically for you query about CSS this is a good starter reference written by a new user: http://codeignitercamp.blogspot.com/2007/08/codeigniter-tutorial-2.html

Answer (score 1):

Just found a pretty good series on the basics of it:

http://capsizedesigns.com/blog/2008/05/getting-started-with-codeigniter-part-1/
http://capsizedesigns.com/blog/2008/05/getting-started-with-codeigniter-part-2/
http://capsizedesigns.com/blog/2008/05/getting-started-with-codeigniter-part-3/